# Building/Running CLN on Debian 11

Tags: core-lightning, compiling

Is there a way to build or run CLN on Debian 11? The docs/INSTALL.md file lists several operating systems, but none of them is Debian.

I tried following the directions for Ubuntu, but that resulted in the following error:

```
cd external/libwally-core && ./tools/autogen.sh
/bin/sh: 1: ./tools/autogen.sh: not found
make: *** [external/Makefile:83: external/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwally-core-build/src/libwallycore.la] Error 127
```

A docker image would probably work in my case too, or any pre-compiled version that was linked with all necessary libraries. Do such builds exist for CLN? If so, where can I find them?

Ultimately, I need to restore a CLN node and wallet that used to be running on a system that has had a hardware failure. CLN was shutdown normally before the hardware failure, so it should work, but the only system I will have available in the near future is running Debian 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian is the basis for the Ubuntu distribution, as such following the Ubuntu documentation will work for Debian systems too.

That aside, the error you mention indicates that one of the `git` submodules was not initialized after checkout.

You can initialize and sync all submodules with the following command anywhere in the repository:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Then follow the usual instructions.